# How to use numpy.meshgrid to plot a function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I use `numpy.meshgrid` method to draw a 3D plot in Python. the drawing is over variables `d1, d2` but I have a function consist of array with 7 elements which is 3 elements are independent from `d1, d2`. When I try to draw my graph I face this error:

`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (120,120)`

When I debug my code I see the array elements which are independent from `d1, d2` has shape of 1 but the other ones have shape of 120. How I can draw such a function using `numpy.meshgrid` method ?

Thanks. The whole code is like as follows:

```
import numpy
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

def function(a, b, c, d1, d2):
    Q = numpy.ones(7)

    EV = []
    EV.append(1 / (a + b))
    EV.append(1 / (a + b + c))
    EV.append(1 / (a + b + c))
    EV.append((1 - numpy.exp(-c * d1)) / c)
    EV.append((1 - numpy.exp(-c * d2)) / (c + a))
    EV.append((1 - numpy.exp(-c * d1)) / c)
    EV.append((1 - numpy.exp(-c * d2)) / (c + a))

    return numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(Q, EV) / numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(Q, EV)))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# Make data.
d1 = numpy.arange(0, 6, 0.05)
d2 = numpy.arange(0, 6, 0.05)
X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(d1, d2)

# Plot the surface.
ax.set_zlim(2.00, 8.00)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, function(1, 1, 1, X, Y), cmap='viridis', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

# Customize the z axis.
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

# Add a color bar which maps values to colors.
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Your function produces an array of 7 numbers for each input; e.g. `function(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)` is `array([0.42857143, 0.28571429, 0.28571429, 0.        , 0.        ,       0.        , 0.        ])`. How would you want this to be plotted?

Comment: sorry, you are right! 
this is a part of a bigger code. I edit the code recheck it, Imagine I plot the element wise sum of the output array. the error is not because of what you said but I change the code to have a 1D output

Comment: what's the relation to `np.meshgrid`? the error occurs in `numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(Q, EV) / numpy.sum(numpy.multiply(Q, EV)))`. not knowing what it is you want to calculate, anyhow, the result should be of shape (120,120) so you can call it in `plot_surface(X, Y, Z)` as `Z`.

Comment: The point is that my function accept originally single variables not arrays, but when I use ```numpy.meshgrid``` it produces a 2D array of all possible occurrence for ```d1, d2``` and pass it to the function. If you watch my function precisely you could see it produce 7 numbers which is 3 is independent of ```d1, d2``` and the other ones has ```d1, d2``` so the dimension of result is strange. The out is a list of 3 single number and 4 array of 120 x 120.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```py
Z = np.array([[function(1, 1, 1, x, y) for x in d1] for y in d2])
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap='viridis', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

The plot will not be particularly interesting though: First of all, element-wise multiplication by an array of ones is the identity operation, so `np.multiply(Q, EV)` is the same as turning `EV` into an array. For any array `a`, `np.sum(a / np.sum(a))` is equal to 1 (since you can take the constant factor `np.sum(a)` outside of the outer sum). Therefore, `function` is constantly equal to one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer which is completely right. But because matrix calculation has good performance in view of speed I don't want to use ```for loop```. Do you know where is the point, I know it always has the value of 1 but it is not the point. The point is that my function accept originally single variables not arrays, but when I use ```numpy.meshgrid``` it produces a 2D array of all possible occurrence for ```d1, d2``` and pass it to the function.

Comment: If you watch my function precisely you could see it produce 7 numbers which is 3 is independent of ```d1, d2``` and the other ones has ```d1, d2``` so the dimension of result is strange. The output is a list of 3 single number and 4 array of 120 x 120.

Comment: After your edit, the output is a single number, which is, modulo rounding issues, always 1.

Comment: Dear @fuglede this is not a math problem, The error is because the output is always 1 ?? No
I want to know how to use ```meshgrid``` with unbalanced functions.

Comment: I never said that; only that in this particualr case, it causes the plot to be what it ends up being. The method applies in complete generality.